# SignalR send custom class

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I would like to use a custom class on SignalR. But an client side I just get 'null' in the class.

Why am I getting such exceptions?
Exception thrown: 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' in System.Text.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your custom class isn't properly serializable as JSON.

Comment: Just for testing now I have only one string in my class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. That's serializing with JSON.NET *and* System.Text.Json.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the members are "public properties" on the instance to make it all smooth. (or Records). (would be a comment if I had better rep)